# Extracting the bytes from a UTF-8 QString

Tags: qt

I need to extract all the bits from a QString that holds a UTF-8 encoded unicode string.

To be clear, I need the bits to be stored in ideally a byte * (byte array) or alternatively a char *.

The reason I need to do this is because I want to hash the UTF-8 string and the hash function REQUIRES a byte array for the string that is to be hashed.

Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

I just want to extract the bit stream from the QString as it is stored in the QString and dump it into a byte *.  Therefore, ideally, once I have this byte * equivalent, I should be able to make a new QString and initialize it in the QString's constructor with this char * and it should be a proper UTF-8 QString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely looking for the `QByteArray` you get from `QString.toUtf8()`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8

A QString can be re-created from a QByteArray (but be sure to use [QString.fromUtf8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8) since the constructor for QString that takes a QByteArray assumes it's in ASCII).

You can get const (or non-const) access to a char* from a QByteArray...

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#data

...but note that Qt has built-in support for cryptographic hashes of QByteArray, as long as you're happy with MD4, MD5, or SHA-1:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcryptographichash.html

Comment: THANKS! Sorry, Jon Skeet posted first with the same info so I had to give him the answer.

Comment: Actually no...you don't have to give the first answerer any priority.  There is a natural bias to the first answerer getting more upvotes, but the accepted answer should be whichever is best for your purposes.  You can even change which answer you accept if you've already accepted one, and a better answer comes later.  Do avoid the problem on meta known as "fastest gun in the west": http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19533/141442